# Prolog member/2 predicate

Tags: list, prolog, member

Why does prolog answer false to: `member([5], [2, 5]).`?

Is there a way to work around it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because the first argument is in a list. If you try `?- member(5,[2,5]).` Prolog will succeed.

Comment: The predicate is `member`, not `subset` or `sublist` or `subsequence`. So it succeeds if the first argument is a *member* of the list given in the second argument. The list `[5]` is not a member of the list `[2, 5]`. However, `[5]` would be a member of the list `[2, [5]]`, so `member([5], [2, [5]])` would succeed.

Comment: @lurker: That's actually pretty concise and to the point. You should post it as an answer. I would definitely upvote that.

Comment: Thank you, @tas, I shall do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the SWI Prolog documentation for [member/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2):

> **member(**?Elem, *?List* **)**
>
> True if `Elem` is a member of `List`.

The predicate is *member*. It is not *subset* or *sublist* or *subsequence*. It succeeds if the first argument is a member (that is, an *element*) of the list given in the second argument. The element `[5]` is not a member of the list `[2, 5]` since the element `[5]` isn't 2 and it isn't 5. However, `[5]` would be a member of the list `[2, [5]]`, so `member([5], [2, [5]])` would succeed.

Comment: So what about `member(a,[a|non_list])`?

Comment: @false that's an extra credit question, answer being "succeed", as would `member(b, [a,b,c|non_list])`.. :)

Answer (score 7):

> Why does Prolog answer false to: `member([5], [2, 5]).`?

Let's ask Prolog why! Download [`library(diadem)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/diadem.pl) into your working directory and:

```
?- use_module(diadem).
   true.

?- member([5], [2,5]).? Expl.
   Expl = member([_|_], [2, 5])
;  ... .
```

Not only does it fail but also a generalization fails:instead of `[5]` that is a list with a single element 5, we have now simply at least one element - no matter which. So we can take the value for `Expl` as a query which still fails. Something in the remaining goal must thus be the culprit.

```
?- member([_|_], [2, 5]).
   false.
```

Note also what was *not* generalized away: The two elements are still here! If they would be variables, the query would succeed! Generalize the query a bit:

```
?- member([5], [2, Any]).
   Any = [5].
```

Now it succeeds!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are looking for another predicate?
From the SWI Prolog documentation for [subset/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subset/2):

> **subset(** *+SubSet*, *+Set* **)**
>   True if all elements of *SubSet* belong to *Set* as well.

It works as expected:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.5.5)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.

?- subset([5], [2, 5]).
true.

?- subset([5, 3], [2, 3, 5, 7]).
true.

?- subset([5, 3], [2, 5]).
false.
```